# Random # Guessing Game Infinite Loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite

For my Java class, I'm supposed to make a random number guessing game. I've been stuck on a loop I created for the past couple of days. The output of the program is always an infinite loop and I can't see why. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
/*
  This program will generate a random number. 
  It will ask the user to guess what number was generated and say
  if the guess is too high or low.

*/

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Number is : " + randNum);
        int userGuess = 0;
        int success = 0;
        System.out.println("Guess the number: ");
        userGuess = input.nextInt();

        while(success == 0)
        {

            if(userGuess > randNum){
                System.out.println("Too high");
            }
            else if(userGuess < randNum){
                System.out.println("Too high");  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Something is very wrong."); 
            }

        }
            if(userGuess == randNum){
                success++;
                System.out.println("You got it! Play again?");
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: You never update `userGuess` after the first evaluation. And `success` does not change within the loop, so once the code enters it can never get out because the loop condition will never become `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You put the **if** that checks if the input is equal to the number outside the while, so the cycle never ends.

Here is the code fixed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Number is : " + randNum);
        int userGuess = 0;
        int success = 0;
        System.out.println("Guess the number: ");
        userGuess = input.nextInt();

        while(success == 0) {
            if(userGuess > randNum) {
                System.out.println("Too high");
            } else if(userGuess < randNum) {
                System.out.println("Too high");  
            } else if(userGuess == randNum) {
                success++;
                System.out.println("You got it! Play again?");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Something is very wrong.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution made the success condition work, but the too high and too low options still result in infinite loops. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I added breaks after each fail condition so that I wouldn't get an infinite loop. I tried this earlier, but I kept getting errors.

This is the completed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Number is : " + randNum);
        int userGuess = 0;
        boolean success = false;

        System.out.println("Guess the number: ");
        userGuess = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

        while(success == false){
            if(userGuess > randNum) {
                System.out.println("Too high,try again");
                break;
            } else if(userGuess < randNum) {
                System.out.println("Too low");
                break;  
            } else if(userGuess == randNum) {
                success = true;
                System.out.println("You got it! Play again?");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Something is very wrong.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```